# Haskell - How to best to represent a programming language's grammar?

Tags: compiler-construction, haskell, grammar, representation

I've been looking at Haskell and I'd quite like to write a compiler in it (as a learning exercise), since a lot of its innate features can be readily applied to a compiler (particularly a recursive descent compiler).

What I can't quite get my head around is how to represent a language's grammar in a Haskell-ian way. My first thought was to use recursive data type definitions, but I can't see how I use them to match against keywords in the language ("if") for example.

Thoughts and suggestions greatly appreciated,

Pete

Comment: With what little I know, I'd recommend looking at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours (it uses Parsec etc.) but I'm not leaving it as an answer because it's quite possibly a terrible one. Hopefully someone who knows better will answer (and then I'll delete this comment).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A recursive data type is fine for this.  For example, given the language:

```
expr ::= var
      |  "true"
      |  "false"
      |  "if" expr "then" expr "else" expr
      |  "(" expr ")"
```

an example expression in this language would be:

```
if true then x else (if false then y else true)
```

Your Haskell data type would look something like this:

```
data Expr = Var String
          | Lit Bool
          | If Expr Expr Expr
```

Your parser then takes care to translate, e.g., `x` into `Var "x"`, and `true` into `Lit True`, etc.  I.e.:

```
parse "if x then false else true" 
  ==  If (Var "x") (Lit False) (Lit True)
```

For writing parsers you can roll your own using the techniques mentioned in Norman's answer, or using [Parsec](http://legacy.cs.uu.nl/daan/parsec.html) or use parser generators like [Happy](http://www.haskell.org/happy/).

Answer (score 20):

You represent programs using mutually recursive algebraic data types, and to parse programs you use **parsing combinators**.  There are a million flavors; you will find three helpful tutorial papers on the [schedule for my class](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/comp150fp/ss.html) for Monday, March 23, 2009.  They are

- Graham Hutton and Erik Meijer, *[Functional Pearl: Monadic parsing in Haskell](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/comp150fp/archive/graham-hutton/monadic-parsing-jfp.pdf)* (1998)

  Graham Hutton, *[Higher-order Functions for Parsing](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/comp150fp/archive/graham-hutton/parsing.ps.gz)* (1992)

  Jeroen Fokker, *[Functional Parsers](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/comp150fp/archive/jeroen-fokker/parsers.ps.gz)* (1995)

The Hutton and Meijer paper is the shortest and simplest, but it uses monads, which are not obvious to the amateur.  However they have a very nice grammar of and parser for expressions.  If you don't grok monads yet, Fokker's tutorial is the one.

Comment: Awesome..links. You are the Prog language guru around here. Thanks

Comment: Ironically, I think learning about parser combinators is the best way to understand monads.

Comment: The problem with parser combinators is they do not usually support left recursive grammars...

Comment: @CallumRogers the same is true of handwritten recursive-descent parsers.  Niklaus Wirth showed the way years ago: instead of left recursion, use sequences.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can look at some real-world projects to see how they do it?

Less than a week ago, the [Language-Python](http://Projects.Haskell.Org/language-python/) project was [announced](http://Haskell.Org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2009-March/058051.html) on the [Haskell-Cafe mailinglist](http://Haskell.Org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/). It's a [Python](http://Python.Org/) parser implemented in Haskell, using the [Happy](http://Haskell.Org/happy/) parser generator and [Alex](http://Haskell.Org/alex/) lexer generator.

And of course, there is [Pugs](http://PugsCode.Org/), an implementation of [Perl 6](http://Dev.Perl.Org/perl6/) in Haskell (the first implementation of Perl 6 that conforms to a significant subset of the Perl 6 specification).

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from the tone of your question whether this is the first time you're attempting to write a compiler, or if you've written compilers before and are looking for advice specific to Haskell.  If you're already a compiler guru, what little advice I have to offer isn't going to help. :)

Programming language grammars are commonly represented in [BNF form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form), which can be used by tools like Yacc or Bison to parse source code.  I don't know if this counts as a Haskell-ian way to do it, but it's the only way that I've heard of.  With some digging around you can probably dig up a tool to generate Haskell code from a BNF grammar; I found [this tool](http://www.cs.chalmers.se/Cs/Research/Language-technology/BNFC/) which claims to be able to do that.

A quick Google search turned up [this BNF grammar for Haskell](http://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/254/grammar/haskell.html), and there are probably others out there, in case you want to write a compiler for Haskell (maybe you'd like to write a Haskell compiler in Haskell?)  BNF grammars for C and Java seem to be popular.

Finally, if you're looking for a book about compiler design, the classic text is ["The Dragon Book"](http://books.google.ca/books?id=1sGvAAAACAAJ).

Comment: The Dragon Book is indeed a classic, but I've heard that current thinking about compiler implementation has passed it by (e.g., JIT runtime optimizations, etc).  I'm no authority myself, just a shameless passer of innuendo.  8)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm looking for advice more  specific to Haskell, and I'd rather not use a tool (I'm trying to learn not have a tool do it all for me :) ).

Comment: Writing compilers in Haskell is quite a different (and more pleasant) exercise compared to writing compilers in imperative languages. [And @duffymo: 'innuendo' probably doesn't mean what you think it means :)]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no Haskell grammar for [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list), but perhaps you can use the link cited above to create one.  ANTLR is a great Java-based parser generator.

Steve Yegge has a nice [blog](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2007/06/rich-programmer-food.html) about writing compilers, if you need more motivation.  It's entertaining.